# Objective C: How do i smoothen the brush like a real brush?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, core-graphics

I am building a brush app, it's almost finish and what i did was just a basic brush/drawing tool. I want to give it a more brush-like feel because in my current output it has angles and it doesn't look like a real brush ink.

here's my code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touchSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentTouch.y -= 20;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [touchDraw.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, touchDraw.frame.size.width, touchDraw.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 35.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), redAmt, blueAmt, greenAmt, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), endingPoint.x, endingPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    touchDraw.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    endingPoint = currentTouch;

    touchMoved++;

    if (touchMoved == 10) {
        touchMoved = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the quadCurve instead of addLineToPoint.. Quad Curve make a line in a two points that don't have an angle and make your line a curve..

```
CGPoint midPoint(CGPoint p1,CGPoint p2)
        {
         return CGPointMake ((p1.x + p2.x) * 0.5,(p1.y + p2.y) * 0.5);
        }

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event//upon moving

{   
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = currentTouch;
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint2, previousPoint1); 
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentTouch, previousPoint1);

    // here's your ticket to the finals.. 
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that you'll be able to use touch events for this without getting the angles you describe. The resolution of the events just aren't discrete enough.

OpenGL seems a better fit. Check out Apple's [GLPaint sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html) for an example.

Comment: yes, i have it, but it's a bit confusing for me. The whole Objective C is new to me as well as OpenGL. Do you know someone or any link that explains it well?? I swear it's really confusing 'coz reading it by myself really gives me nothing.

Comment: Not really sure what's confusing to you. If you gave a little more detail, maybe I could help? Do you know C? You should start there with the K&R C book (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language). Anything by Aaron Hillegass is worth reading (http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/objective-c_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide for starters). Also don't forget Apple's WWDC videos!

Comment: the whole OpenGL actually... i have a background in C that's why i didn't have a hard time understanding Objective C. Thanks! i found The Big Nerd Ranch in our library!