# iOS App Development: Achieving Zen Brush Smoothness Effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I'm done with the painting app that i'm working for my project but i want to enhance it more.

I want to achieve something like the [Zen Brush](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zen-brush/id382200873?mt=8), not exactly like that but i want to achieve a texture like that.

Do you guys have an idea how the developers of Zen Brush achieve their brush effect?

what framework should i use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C: How do i smoothen the brush like a real brush?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117003/objective-c-how-do-i-smoothen-the-brush-like-a-real-brush)